# Javascript: what are some guidelines on how to define new data types?

Tags: javascript, types

Suppose you are creating the data type and expose its behavior.

Can you give some examples of when would you use:

- a function & new:

  ```
  // define new data type
  var CustomDataType= function(){ 
                        this.a='whatever';
                        this.doX= function(){/*some code*/};
                      }

  // create a new instance of our custom data type
  var obj= new customDataType();
  ```
- an object literal & Object.create:

  ```
  // define new data type
  var customDataType = {
                         a: 'whatever',
                         doX: function(){/*some code*/}
                       }

  // create a new instance of our custom data type
  var obj= Object.create(customDataType);
  ```
- a function that builds your object:

  ```
  function customDataTypeFactory(options){
    return {
             a: 'whatever',
             doX: function(){/*some code*/}
           }
  };

  // create a new instance of our custom data type
  var obj= customDataTypeFactory(options);
  ```

I feel this could be labeled duplicate for: `new` vs `Object.create` but my main interest is not in discussing which one is better but rather to know if there are specific use cases where one should be preferred over the others.

I have read many posts on related questions and the book from Crockford: Javascript: the good parts. So far I have concluded that it is a matter of preference, tough the advice from Crockford resonates a lot with me  to me: "try to avoid the features that are dangerous and unnecessary"... I'm talking about `new`.

Comment: Your first and third versions put properties directly on the new object. In your second version, the object inherits the properties. I don't know that there's any concrete answer to your question. The first one uses a constructor if you invoke using `new`, and `instanceof` will work to identify that object. The third one doesn't require the use of `new`, but `instanceof` won't be as useful. The second one again inherits the properties, so building several objects that way will all share the data, and all the objects will observe updates to the inherited object.

Comment: ...and don't get too hung up on Crockford's danger warnings. I think he worries a little too much. I mean, take it all in, but take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: `this.doX=` should be `doX :` in the last two snippets

Answer (score 8):

I'll start with the way I usually define classes:

```
function CustomDataType(a)
{
  this.a = a;
  this.b = 2;
}
CustomDataType.prototype = {
  doX : function () {}
};
var obj = new CustomDataType(1);
```

I assign variables in the constructor because `F.prototype = { a : [1,2,3]; }` is problematic, the array will be shared between instances unless the property is reinitialized in the constructor (problematic for all non-primitive types). And it's also needed when the property somehow depends on the arguments to the constructor. I declare methods in the prototype so that they are shared between all instances, if you use inheritance it means you can have super calls, it will also lead to less memory usage since the method only has to be allocated once (though that probably isn't a big issue).

I have never used `Object.create`, I don't see any reason to do to that unless you are into some insane dynamic hackery.

I use object literals whenever it feels unnecessary to create a separate class for the objects, for instance if it's arguments to a methods (so callers don't have to explicitly instantiate something), or if it's some internal values that shouldn't be accessed by anyone else.

Your factory is essentially the same as the object literal. I suppose it can be useful if you need to create some jsonesque structure and set some default values.

I don't see why `new` would be dangerous or unnecessary, in what context did he say that?

But I think a lot of it comes down to taste. Be consistent and don't complicate things.

Comment: Crockford's problem with `new` is: "*If you forget to include the `new` prefix when calling a constructor function, then `this` will not be bound to a new object. Sadly, this will be bound to the global object, so instead of augmenting your new object, you will be clobbering global variables. <snip> A much better alternative is to not use `new` at all.*"

Comment: Ah, I remember reading about that, probably from him. You could do something like
`function C(x) { if (this == window) return new C(x); this.x = x; }`
I mess up a lot when i write JS, but I have never forgotten to write `new`...

Comment: @AdamBergmark wouldn't it be better to throw an error to enforce using new?

Comment: If the code can detect and recover by itself, then no error is needed. Errors should be about **exceptional** situations where the dev action is required. – I remember to have seen this pattern, of instantiating automatically when called without `new`, in several projects (maybe is a practice/convention in JS world).