# creating a unique keyword in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, keyword

The objective is to create a new keyword 'int' that has the same semantics as the named type 'number.'
I know that I can achieve the same behavior by using the type 'number' but I have been specifically asked to implement a new keyword in typescript. I am interviewing for a research project at my school.

An example use-case would be the following:

```
function add(x:int, y:int) {
  return x + y; 
}
```

I have been struggling to achieve this exact use-case. I have spent several hours going through the [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf).

I have read through the Types, Classes and Interfaces sections to try and figure out how to do this; no luck thus far.

I know I can achieve something similar using an interface like so:

```
interface int {
   n: number;
}
```

But I'd have to implement the function like this:

```
function add(x:int, y:int) {
   return x.n + y.n;
}
```

I am completely new to typescript so any direction is greatly appreciated - thanks.

A few basic examples on [typescriptlang.org](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Tutorial/)

Comment: Why don't you want to use `number` if it has the same semantic?

Comment: That's a great question. I was asked by a professor at my school to 
"introduce a new keyword 'int' where the add(x:int, y:int) function above could compile in typescript, and that it should have the same semantics as 'number'" to potentially help work on a project with him. I think he wants to see if I can implement a new typescript keyword.

Comment: Take a look at the following links:

 - [Javascript: what are some guidelines on how to define new data types?][1]
 - [Is there a library for a Set data type in Javascript?][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857682/javascript-what-are-some-guidelines-on-how-to-define-new-data-types
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342749/is-there-a-library-for-a-set-data-type-in-javascript

Comment: Those are more specific to js, this case is more specific to typescript semantics - thanks for your help though.

Comment: The compiler and parser is all available/exposed and you might be able to extend the language in a more meaningful way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question, your professor has realised a limitation of TypeScript.

He has specifically asked you to make an add function. This is important because TypeScript doesn't support overloading of operators (such as `+`).

However, you can write a function that accepts two ints and returns an int using the unary add operator as shown below. Only the code inside the function needs to understand there is odd stuff going on. Everything outside of the function thinks ints exist.

This wouldn't stop you from passing floats using the int type.

```
interface int extends Number {

}

function add(x: int, y: int) : int {
    return +x + +y;
}

var a: int = 1;
var b: int = 2;

var c = add(a, b);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I was playing around with extending int to Number, but I wouldn't have guessed to use a unary operator. I'm new to typescript, different but interesting way to avoid js patterns I suppose.

Comment: No problems. The unary + is a shorthand convert to number, so use with care... `var num = +"5"'` is okay, but `var num = +"hello";` is a bit strange :)

Answer (score 0):

According to http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/119, you can use

```
interface int extends number {}
```

You also might be interesting in [feature: int and float types](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1858).

Comment: I get the following error: Invalid '+' expression - types not known to support the addition operator. I then changed number to Number which is its parent class, but then I get the following error: Invalid '+' expression - types not known to support the addition operator. Thanks for your help though - i'll keep trying.